# How to specify the system database location when installing SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, installation

It seems that we can't specify a location for the system databases when installing SQL Server. I want to know whether this is true. Take a look at the image I attached.

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can select the root directory path here

[image: change it here]

Comment: So, should we chech "named instance" and leave it empty, and then change the "Instance root directory" to <drive>:\.. ? If we set the named instance to nothing, will it be like "default instance" then?

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, I'll add a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx) to the correct procedure for moving system databases - just in case you already installed in the default locations and later wish to move these databases.